# Design DB to calculate prize based on distance of cities

Tags: python, django, database

I am working on a side project to calculate the prize of the service based on the city distances.

In my prize table I have values like below:

| CATEGORY | DISTANCE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Category A | < 100 km | 10EUR |
| Category A | From 100 km to 300 km | 50 EUR |
| Category A | > 300 km | 100 EUR |

My idea is to prepare a DB structure like below:

| CATEGORY | DISTANCE_FROM | DISTANCE_TO | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Category A | 0 | 100 | 10 |
| Category A | 100 | 300 | 50 |
| Category A | 300 | x | 100 |

Is this the right approach? I am also wondering how to later get the correct value if for example distance is 150 km?

The project will be build in Django, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there is no overlap in distance ranges, you could use only the DISTANCE_FROM column and find the applicable row using

```
SELECT TOP 1 
... 
WHERE DISTANCE_FROM < 150 
ORDER BY DISTANCE_FROM DESC
```